# How can i import code and input on ideone and get output?

Tags: compilation

I have a website that needs to compile the code and i want to use https://ideone.com, but I can't find an api (or just need an iframe). All I found is a script tag like:

```
<script src="http://ideone.com/e.js/AcLkHm" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And it just shows the code not the output:

[image]

I don't know how to import my code and input and get the output for my website. So how can I solve this?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use Ideone? Woud running their code (or some similar framework) on your own server be an option? I don't have a particular solution in mind, just looking for clarification.

Comment: yes, ideone is just an option, can u suggest me other ones that i can import code and input and get the output on my web?

Comment: https://ideone.com/sphere-engine suggests you'll need a paid license.

Comment: Via http://www.moreofit.com/similar-to/www.ideone.com/Top_10_Sites_Like_Ideone/ I found http://codepad.org/about which seems less commercially encumbered, though I don't see any obvious API documentation.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have found a module that's suitable for my nodejs web: https://github.com/remoteinterview/compilebox

Answer (score 2):

[Ideone](http://ideone.com) uses Sphere Engine (https://sphere-engine.com) (**Compilers** module) as a backend service for executing programs. Sphere Engine service is delivered as a **RESTful API**.